# force user to refresh spa

Tags: ajax, single-page-application

Imagine, you're having SPA.

The website never gets refreshed for the new data is always fetched via ajax.
It means that your users may not refresh the website even in 7 days in a row for example (I mean, you just close your mac with a chrome open, on the next day you open computer, open website and continue working).

The user has not refreshed the website in 7 days in a row, but you made lots of updates and bug fixes.

How would you go about such situation?